# How can label an edge of a tree which was manually added?

Tags: labels, tikz-trees, forest, trees, edge

One can use TikZ to create a tree manually , or use the *forest package* to make the process easier. Below I show how I can use the *forest package* to create a binary tree, and turn it into a recombinant tree by using TikZ to draw some edges manually. While I can add a label to any edge which wasn't manually added (as I do below with the label *Kangaroo*), I cannot figure out how to add a label to an edge which *was* manually added. For example, how do I label the edge from the node `$S_1(T)=4$` to the node `$S_2(TH)=S_2(HT)=8$` (see the following picture)?

[image: recombinant binary tree]

I simply tried copy-pasting the same command (i.e. `edge label={node [near end, above  left, font=\footnotesize]{Kangaroo}}`) in the code below after `(T) -- (TH)`, but it didn't work.

```
\begin{forest}  
for tree={grow'=east}
[{$S_0=8$ },
    [{$S_1(T)=4$ },name=T,  
        [{$S_2(TT)=2$}, edge label={node [near end, above  left, font=\footnotesize]{Kangaroo}} ]
        [, phantom]
    ]
    [, phantom
        [{\qquad $S_2(TH)=S_2(HT)=8$},name=TH  ] 
    ]
    [{$S_1(H)=16$}, name=H
        [, phantom]
        [{$S_2(HH)=32$} ] 
    ]   
] 
\draw (T) -- (TH)  (H) -- (TH);
\end{forest}
```

Fyi, the [,phantom] nodes are just empty nodes to help with spacing, they are not really necessary.

Comment: please have a look at the answer to see if it meets your requirement

Comment: please have alook at the revised answer

Comment: This answers my question, thanks ! Fyi, I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't show because I am a noobie

Comment: you may like to accept the answer be clicking the green check mark on the left side of the answer

Comment: Ah ah! Done, thanks! Btw, if I may ask, what is the difference in behaviour between writing `s sep=2em` versus  `s=2em`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `l sep` dimension

Also the `sloped` version of label with positioning `pos=0.5` or midway adjusted with the help of `yshift`

[image]

```
\begin{forest} 
    for tree={grow'=east, s sep=2em, l sep=2cm}
    [{$S_0=8$ },
    [{$S_1(T)=4$ },name=T,  
    [{$S_2(TT)=2$}, edge label={node [pos=0.5, above, yshift=-4pt ,sloped, 
     font=\scriptsize]{Kangaroo}} ]
    [, phantom]
    ]
    [, phantom
    [{\qquad $S_2(TH)=S_2(HT)=8$},name=TH  ] 
    ]
    [{$S_1(H)=16$}, name=H
    [, phantom]
    [{$S_2(HH)=32$} ] 
    ]   
    ] 
    \draw (T) -- (TH)  (H) -- (TH);
\end{forest}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Add the following --

```
\node at ($(T)!0.5!(TH)$)
        [rotate=-22, yshift=5pt]
        {\footnotesize\color{red} Kangaroo};
```

**MWE**

```
 \begin{forest} 
    for tree={grow'=east, s sep=2em, l sep=2cm}
    [{$S_0=8$ },
    [{$S_1(T)=4$ },name=T,  
    [{$S_2(TT)=2$}, edge label={node [pos=0.5,above,yshift=-4pt,sloped, 
    font=\footnotesize]{Kangaroo}} ]
    [, phantom]
    ]
    [, phantom
    [{\qquad $S_2(TH)=S_2(HT)=8$},name=TH  ] 
    ]
    [{$S_1(H)=16$}, name=H
    [, phantom]
    [{$S_2(HH)=32$} ] 
    ]   
    ] 
    \draw (T) -- (TH)  (H) -- (TH);
    \node at ($(T)!0.5!(TH)$)
    [rotate=-22, yshift=5pt]
    {\footnotesize\color{red} Kangaroo};
\end{forest}
```

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood my question, so I have clarified it further. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This answers my question, thanks !

Comment: you may like to upvote the answer